# What is the type of a class name follow by parenthesis

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I can't understand such syntax in https://github.com/hmenke/boost_matheval/blob/master/src/qi/parser.hpp#L43

```
struct bar {
    bar() {}
};

template<typename _T>
class foo {
public:
    foo() {}
};

...
foo<bar()> fb;
...
```

What is the type of _T in the specialization of the templates foo? How to use _T in foo?

Comment: `_T` doesn't have a type, it *is* a type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the type of a function. When you declare

```
bar function();
```

I.e., a function taking no arguments and returning a `bar`, then `function` has a type, and it's `bar()`. `_T` stands for it. As though you have an alias

```
using _T = bar();
```

or

```
typedef bar _T();
```

It's not an uncommon type to see. For instance, function types are what [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) accepts. How to use it depends on the purpose of the class template, and how it's potentially specialized.